# How to get the p-value for a binary logistic regression model, not the individual predictors?

Tags: regression, logistic, generalized-linear-model, p-value

I ran a stepwise binary logistic regression model using `glm` in R. `emoteModel <- glm(SelfReport ~ ., family = binomial(link = 'logit'), data = train[, 1:8]) %>% stepAIC(trace = FALSE)`

It gave me p-value for individual predictors (all of which are numeric in the range [0-100]), as follows:
[image]

However, I need the p-value of the entire model as well to check significance of the model. Is there any way to obtain it? I tried anova, but it gives me the p-values of individual predictors only. Please help!

[image]

Would it be appropriate to use the chi square test as follows? If so, then p<<<<0.05 indicate that the model is not a good fit for data? 
[image]

Update: I created the nullmodel using `nullmodel <- glm(SelfReport ~ 1, family = binomial(link = 'logit'), data = train[, 1:8]) %>% stepAIC(trace = FALSE)`, and then ran `anova(emoteModel, nullmodel)`. it did not give me the p-value as shown below:
[image]

Comment: You compare to the model with just an intercept. Stick those two models into R’s ‘anova’ function.

Comment: why to compare with model that has intercept only, and not the actual input? also how do i get the model with just the intercept?

Comment: I tried with null model, it did not give me the p-val

Comment: When you call “summary” on an “lm” object in R, it gives you a p-value. This is for the hypothesis test that the non-intercept parameters all equal zero. It’s the same idea in logistic regression. Now what did you try with the null model that didn’t give you a p-value?

Comment: anova(m1, m2, test = “LRT”)

Comment: I thought the function gave p-values, but it’s easy enough to get the p-value from a $\chi^2$ distribution (“pchisq(deviance, dof)” or maybe “1-pchisq”). The package “lmtest” has some functions in it that I recall giving p-values for likelihood ratio testing.

Comment: You know this, but for anyone who stumbles on this, the deviance and degrees of freedom should be positive.

Comment: did i specify the null model correctly, in the code above? is that how it is done?

Comment: @MarkWhite that worked, but I just want to make sure if I specified the null model correctly. and if p<0.05 means that my model is better or other way around.

Comment: 1) How did you specify the null model? 2) You’re testing a null hypothesis of all non-intercept terms are zero with an alternative hypothesis that the null is false (so at least one is not zero).

Comment: Ok, I see how you specified the null. You’re correct to give “~1”, though I don’t follow what you’re doing with AIC.

Comment: I am not really doing anything with AIC. is my interpretation correct?